# What's it called? Feature in remote desktop software? Client is told to put a code in a website which starts a remote desktop session?

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer

I saw it once while I was fixing this someone's computer.

We went to a website and put some numbers in a box. These numbers then prompted an executable which we downloaded and ran, which then started a single-use remote desktop session. I also see scammers using this method all the time. Is this possible on TeamViewer? What is this feature called, and does it even have a name?

I know I could just send them a TeamViewer link and have them text a picture of a link, but having a one step process is really nice.

Comment: Yes this is possible using the paid version you can generate an executable.

Answer (score 0):

The most similar feature that I know of in TeamViewer is their "TeamViewer QuickSupport" product, however lots of other companies sell similar products. Since most of these are offered as Software as a Service (SaaS) there is often a fee associated with hosting the ability to accept new remote sessions from incoming clients.

In my practice I've used, but there are many more:

- Fast Support/Remote Support from GoToAssist: https://help.gotoassist.com/remote-support/products
- Remote Support from BeyondTrust: https://www.beyondtrust.com/remote-support
- ConnectWise Contro: https://control.connectwise.com/support/features/remote-support